# How to fix this code's wrong answer to a few test case?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a question of maximum pairwise product. For my code, the answer given to the value of n=2, and values being 100000 and 90000 in the given order, is 10000000000. I tried another way to solve this and it worked but I want to know what is wrong with this solution.

I tried few other test cases and they worked. Test case n=2, 100000 and 90000, gives the wrong answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

long long MaxPairwiseProduct(const std::vector<int>& numbers) {
    long long max_product = 0;
    int n = numbers.size();
    int a=-1,b=-1;
    for (int first = 0; first < n; ++first)
    {
        if ((a==-1) || numbers[a]<numbers[first])
            a=first;
        }
    for (int second=0; second<n; ++second)
    {
        if((b==-1) || numbers[b]<numbers[second])
        {
            if (b!=a)
                b=second;
        }
    }
    max_product=(long long )numbers[a]*numbers[b];
    return max_product;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    std::cout << MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Everyone expects the output of the given case to be 9000000000 but the actual output is 10000000000.

Comment: `a` and `b` are both zero in your test case, so you get the answer of 100000 squared.

Comment: how to fix the error? I initialized the loop to change the values to the maximum and second maximum values, but its still not working

Comment: So what is the code supposed to do? Find the maximum product of two different numbers in the vector? What happens if the same number occurs twice in the vector?

Comment: Find the maximum product of two distinct numbers in a sequence of non-negative integers. Input: A sequence of non-negative integers. Output: The maximum value that can be obtained by multiplying two diﬀerent elements from the sequence. Note that 'indexa' and 'indexb' should be diﬀerent ,though it may be the case that two numbers are same at different positions..

Comment: Even with 2nd max detection corrected, your procedure fails for `[-2, -1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: read the question in the comment above. "non-negative integers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change `b!=a` to `second!=a`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

long long MaxPairwiseProduct(const std::vector<int>& numbers) {
    long long max_product = 0;
    int n = numbers.size();
    int a=0,b=-1;
    for (int first = 0; first < n; ++first)
    {
        if (numbers[a]<numbers[first])
            a=first;
    }
    for (int second=0; second<n; ++second)
    {
        if((b==-1) || numbers[b]<numbers[second])
        {
            if (second!=a)
                b=second;
        }
    }
    max_product=(long long )numbers[a]*numbers[b];
    return max_product;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    std::cout << MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. it works correctly. it works fine even without the grouping of numbers. the problem with my code was the **b!=a** which should've been **second!=a**

Comment: `add new variable to count how many times [] the maximum number [occurs]` whatfor? Preventing the value of `a` getting assigned to `b` should suffice. How about negative numbers? Less than two elements? (Why name the index variable `first`/`second`?)

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to work (untested).

```
for (int first = 0; first < n; ++first)
{
    if (a == -1 || numbers[a] < numbers[first])
        a = first;
}
for (int second = 0; second < n; ++second)
{
    if (second != a && (b == -1 || numbers[b] < numbers[second]))
        b = second;
}
```